# Undefined reference to class methods using Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files, resource-files

Coming from the Java/Eclipse world, just wanted to brush up on C++ and using Code::Blocks.

Was making a basic class and am having trouble implementing it to my main file.

Getting "undefined reference to 'Time::Time(int, int, int)'" and undefined reference errors to all of my methods used in my main.cpp file.

Tried rebuilding, tried re-adding the files to the console project. Not sure what the problem is. I'm fairly rusty with Code::Blocks so maybe it's something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

main.cpp

```
#include "Time.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Time current();
    Time current(12,0,0);

    cout << "Current time." << endl;
    current.displayTime();

    cout << "\nSet time to 22:29:30." << endl;
    current.setTime(22,29,30);
    current.displayTime();

    cout << "\nAdd 45 minutes." << endl;
    current.addMinutes(45);
    current.displayTime();

    cout << "\nAdd 45 seconds." << endl;
    current.addSeconds(45);
    current.displayTime();

    cout << "\nAdd 1 hour." << endl;
    current.addHours(1);
    current.displayTime();

    return 0;
}
```

Time.h

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

class Time
{
    public:
        Time(int h, int m, int s);
        Time(int h, int m);
        Time(int h);
        Time();

        virtual ~Time();

        void setTime(int h, int m, int s);
        void setTime(int h, int m);
        void setTime(int h);

        void addHours(int h);
        void addMinutes(int m);
        void addSeconds(int s);

        void displayTime();

        int getHours();
        void setHours(int h);
        int getMinutes();
        void setMinutes(int m);
        int getSeconds();
        void setSeconds(int s);

    protected:

    private:
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
};

#endif // TIME_H
```

Time.cpp

```
#include "Time.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Time::Time(int h, int m, int s)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = s;
}

Time::Time(int h, int m)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = 0;
}

Time::Time(int h)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}

Time::Time()
{
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}

Time::~Time()
{
    //dtor
}

Time::void setTime(int h, int m, int s)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = s;
}

Time::void setTime(int h, int m)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = 0;
}

Time::void setTime(int h)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}

Time::void addHours(int h)
{
    hours += h;

    if (hours > 23)
    {
        hours -= 24;
    }
}

Time::void addMinutes(int m)
{
    minutes += m;

    if (minutes > 59)
    {
        addHours(minutes / 60);
        minutes %= 60;
    }
}

Time::void addSeconds(int s)
{
    seconds += s;

    if (seconds > 59)
    {
        addMinutes(seconds / 60);
        seconds %= 60;
    }
}

Time::void displayTime()
{
    if (hours < 10)
    {
        cout << "0" << hours;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << hours;
    }

    cout << ":";

    if (minutes < 10)
    {
        cout << "0" << minutes;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << minutes;
    }

    cout << ":";

    if (seconds < 10)
    {
        cout << "0" << seconds;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << seconds;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

Time::void setHours(int h)
{
    if (h >= 0 && h <= 23)
    {
        hours = h;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input!\n";
    }
}

Time::int getHours()
{
    return hours;
}

Time::void setMinutes(int m)
{
    if (m >= 0 && m <= 59)
    {
        minutes = m;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input!\n";
    }
}

Time::int getMinutes()
{
    return minutes;
}

Time::void setSeconds(int s)
{
    if (s >= 0 && s <= 59)
    {
        seconds = s;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invald input!\n";
    }
}

Time::int getSeconds()
{
    return seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class name goes before the method name and not before the return type.

So instead of e.g.

```
Time::void setTime(int h)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}
```

it should be

```
void Time::setTime(int h)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}
```

Time.cpp does not compile because of errors and then the linker can't find any of the symbols.

Comment: I changed all of those but am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Did you see syntax errors before you made these changes? If not, it means Code::Blocks does not call the compiler on Time.cpp . I do not use Code::Blocks so I cannot really help here.

Comment: It must have been some kind of Code::Blocks issue. I had added the files to the project using the class wizard but making a new project and adding all of the files to it works fine. Thanks anyway.